# The volume generated by rotating one branch of hyperbola

Tags: calculus

Find the volume generated by rotating one branch of hyperbola

> $x^2-y^2=a^2$

about the $x$-axis, between the limits $x=0$ and $x=2a$ using single-variable calculus/solid of revolution

My solution is:
$V= \int \pi y^2~dx=\frac{2a^3\pi}{3}$
While in the solution manual it’s $\frac{4a^3\pi}{4}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky point here is that there is nothing between $x=0$ and $x=a$. You can draw a graph of the hyperbola to discover this issue.

Just integrating between $x=a$ and $x=2a$ will give the right answer:

$$V=\int_a^{2a}\pi(x^2-a^2)\mathrm{d}x=\frac43\pi a^3$$